# The second iteration of my loop displays the values of a collection in a different order than the first one

Tags: c#, string, foreach

Related part of the code is here:

```
 private async void Start_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {

    timer1.Interval = 50;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
    LoopCheck = true;
    trackBar1.Hide();
    label1.Hide();
    label2.Hide();
    label3.Hide();
    label4.Hide();
    label5.Hide();
    label6.Hide();
    label7.Hide();
    label8.Hide();
    label9.Hide();
    label10.Hide();
    label11.Hide();
    textBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 24F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
        while (LoopCheck)
        {
            foreach (string word in WordsOfFile)
            {

                WordToShow = word;
                await Task.Delay(time);

            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You need to add text by clicking 'Load Text' button", "Error!");

        textBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
        LoopCheck = false;
        timer1.Stop();
        trackBar1.Show();
        label1.Show();
        label2.Show();
        label3.Show();
        label4.Show();
        label5.Show();
        label6.Show();
        label7.Show();
        label8.Show();
        label9.Show();
        label10.Show();
        label11.Show();
    }

}


private void Stop_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    LoopCheck = false;
    timer1.Stop();
    trackBar1.Show();
    label1.Show();
    label2.Show();
    label3.Show();
    label4.Show();
    label5.Show();
    label6.Show();
    label7.Show();
    label8.Show();
    label9.Show();
    label10.Show();
    label11.Show();

}
```

Outside of this code I am showing this `WordToShow` string in a textbox.
When I click `StartButton` this block of code starts. When I click `StopButton` this `LoopCheck` value is set to `false`. That means the loop is stopped. It works well on the first click to start.

After I click on *start* again the words in `WordsOfFile` are not shown in the correct order. That means I am missing something about the `foreach` block.

What could it be?

Comment: What is WordsOfFile?  Is it a `List`?  Give us more code... since we have no idea what those elements are.

Comment: It is an asynchronous process, meaning there's no synchronization and no order...

Comment: I have changed your title into something more descriptive. If this is not what you meant, please clarify your exact problem.

Comment: You're going to need to post a bit more of your code, like where you initialize LoopCheck and WordsToShow and where else you set them and how your Start and Stop methods interact with this loop

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Thank you. This version is more reliable. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `await Task.Delay()`   does is creating delay tasks in every iteration. So even you change `LoppCheck` value from true to false you still have the tasks that were created.  That is why you can see words that are not in the correct order. And also I can say you see words change faster than you assigned. That is because awaited delays are still on work. So you need to cancel that tasks.

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the documentation of MSDN about cancelling  tasks.

Answer (score 1):

`await` keyword tells the program to iterate through the `foreach` and come back when `Task.Delay` is complete. but since `Task.Delay` is not exact which thread comes back from await can't be controlled. And you get your results out of order.

You'll have to implement ordering.

Depending on the goal you're trying to achieve, there might be better options out there.

EDIT:

If all you're trying to do is have a responsive UI, look into [BackgroundWorker class](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker). It may seem complicated at first but its not.

Comment: then, how come it works perfectly fine in the first iteration?

Comment: Because First iteration is FIRST and there are no other threads running and its the FIRST to come back

Comment: So is there a way to add delay between WordToShow = word; line and at the same time keep the application responsive? I have tried Thread.sleep() But it was keeping app stucked.

Comment: If you add delay, you defy the whole purpose of async/await. If all you want to have is responsive UI, look into BackgroundWorker. It allows you to execute long running process on a background thread and update UI when its done.

Comment: I just heard about BackgroundWorker from you. And it looks more what I want. Is it too much to ask "what is await teask.delay() for?".

Comment: async/await and Tasks are very powerfull things. One of the things you could do is if you want to run calculations in parallel, that are not dependent on each other, you could do it that way. And there's alot more to list here